# Warning: Creating default object from empty value Line 63

Tags: php

// im getting an error in my php code " Warning: Creating default object from empty value in Auth.php on line 63 "

```
$shop->Levels = $levels; //Line 63
$shop->Rank = $rank;
$shop->Loading = $loading;
$shop->Gems = $gems;
$shop->Boosts = $boosts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably never initialize `$shop`.

Just add at the top:

```
$shop = new stdClass();
```

Comment: @TommyForWorld you have to put it on line 62 (at least, before the first time you are using it)... if it's not working, please tell me the error, and if it's the same, post the entire code

Comment: @TommyForWorld well that's another problem, because you are passing this object to something that requires  "Last IP" to be set